# List index out of range error every 20 minutes or so

Tags: python, list, indexing

In an IRC bot I'm coding, I have two functions that retrieve the user that sent a message and the message that was sent. It does this by splitting the read buffer line that is sent to the bot into two parts, then uses the second list index to retrieve the user/message. Here's the first part of the code:

```
def getUser(line):
    if "!" in line:
        separate = line.split(":", 2)
        user = separate[1].split("!", 1)[0]
        return user
    else:
        print "Nothing to receive from the server!"
def getMessage(line):
    if ':' in line:
        separate = line.split(":", 2)
        message = separate[2]
        return message
    else:
        print "Nothing to receive from the server!"
```

As you can see, I attempted to form a way to stop itself from timing out from the server when there is nothing to receive from the server; this is where the problem is originating. It'll retrieve a line of nothing, then try to split the nothing, and then it tries to access a list index that is out of range. I have an idea that this might be able to be accomplished using a `try/catch` statement, however I am new to Python and don't know much about this. Here's the rest of the code where the functions are accessed, if it helps:

```
readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
readbuffer = temp.pop()

for line in temp:
    user = getUser(line)
    message = getMessage(line)
```

I am getting the list index error on the line `message = getMessage(line)` and `user = getUser(line)`.

Comment: you can catch the `IndexError` exception

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say on which line you're getting the error.  Just looking at it, I would think it would be this: 

user = separate[1].split("!", 1)[0]

Not quite sure what you are doing here... Can you post an example of the data you're working with?

Comment: @davo36 Just added that in at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Add the error traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is in these lines (probably *in addition to* not checking if `line` is empty string or not, as shown in gariepy's answer):

```
separate = line.split(":", 2)
user = separate[1].split("!", 1)[0]
```

and

```
separate = line.split(":", 2)
message = separate[2]
```

In the first case you are assuming that `separate` has at least 2 elements (as you are using `split` on `separate[1]`), and in the second case you are assuming that `separate` has at least 3 elements (as you are using `split` on `separate[2]`). You should check their lengths first before you access those indices, like so:

```
separate = line.split(":", 2)
if len(separate) >= 2:
    user = separate[1].split("!", 1)[0]
```

and

```
separate = line.split(":", 2)
if len(separate) >= 3:
    message = separate[2]
```

Also, remember to check if `line` is non-empty string or not before you apply split on it, as shown in the other answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to check if the line is empty before using it:

```
def getUser(line):
    if line:
        if "!" in line:
            separate = line.split(":", 2)
            user = separate[1].split("!", 1)[0]
            return user
    print "Nothing to receive from the server!"
def getMessage(line):
    if line:
        if ':' in line:
            separate = line.split(":", 2)
            message = separate[2]
            return message
    print "Nothing to receive from the server!"
```

An empty string, list (or None) will evaluate to False, so the code will stop there and print your message (or you can restructure the if statement if you don't like what I did).  Any non-empty string/list or literal will evaluate to "True" and proceed to the next if check.

Edit:

Adding try/except:

```
def getUser(line):
    try:
        if line:
            if "!" in line:
                separate = line.split(":", 2)
                user = separate[1].split("!", 1)[0]
                return user
        print "Nothing to receive from the server!"
    except (IndexError as e):
        print e
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        raise
```

Comment: @wong2 and will work just fine, due to short-circuiting!

Comment: I tested this out, and it gave me the same IndexError, sadly.

Comment: I added an edit to show you how to do exception handling.